# How to convert RichText which include Unicode into nomal text?

Tags: c++, winapi

RichText:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs24 I have an apple \u20320?\u22909?\par
}
```

Expected after conversion:

> I have an apple 你好

Actual after conversion:

> I have an apple ??

Here is my code change:

```
RichText::In(const wchar_t* text)
{
    CreateTextServices(NULL, &TextHost, &TextServices);

    if (TextServices)
    {
        WPARAM format = SF_RTF | SF_UNICODE;
        long result = 0;
        StreamIn stream(text);
        textServicesInterface->TxSendMessage(EM_STREAMIN, format, (LPARAM)&stream, &result);
    }
}

String RichText::Out() 
{
    WPARAM format = SF_TEXT;
    String result;
    ITextServicesPtr textServicesInterface = TextServices;
    if (textServicesInterface)
    {
        long read = 0;
        StreamOut stream;
        textServicesInterface->TxSendMessage(EM_STREAMOUT, format, (LPARAM)&stream, &read);
        result = stream.Text;
    }
    return result;
}

class Stream:
    public EDITSTREAM
{
public:
    Stream():
        Index(0)
    {
        ZeroMemory(static_cast<EDITSTREAM*>(this), sizeof(EDITSTREAM));
        dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR)this;
    }

    CAtlStringA Text;
    size_t Index;
};

class StreamOut:
    public Stream
{
public:
    StreamOut()
    {
        pfnCallback = CallBack;
    }

private:
    static DWORD CALLBACK CallBack(DWORD_PTR cookie, unsigned char* buffer, long maximumBytes, long *bytesCopied)
    {
        if (NULL != bytesCopied)
        {
            *bytesCopied = 0;
            Stream* stream = (Stream*)cookie;
            if (NULL != stream)
            {
                buffer[maximumBytes] = '\0';
                stream->Text.Insert(stream->Text.GetLength(), (const char*)buffer);
                *bytesCopied = maximumBytes;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Can anyone explain to me what the problem with my code is?

Comment: Are you experiencing the problem on the `EM_STREAMIN` or `EM_STEAMOUT`? You are not using the `SF_UNICODE` flag on the latter.

Comment: I think it's related to "EM_STEAMOUT", after using SF_UNICODE flag for output, I can only get "I".

Comment: Can't answer that since you didn't show the actual code for the `StreamOut` class, or how you are using the resulting `String`.

Comment: Many thanks, and hope this is the info required.

Comment: This article may help you,,https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6cfa4577-8be9-4ec0-bfdd-990eeec38f46/display-unicode-charactersie-chinese-characters-in-richtextbox-control?forum=winforms

Comment: @MOMING if you enable the `SF_UNICODE` flash on output, it outputs UTF-16 text, which explains why you only see `I` when storing the raw text bytes into a `CAtlStringA`, since the 2nd byte is 0x00. Also, your callback is not using the `maximumBytes` parameter correctly, which specifies the number of bytes in the `buffer` parameter. The `buffer` is not null-terminated data, but your `Text.Insert()` assumes it is. Do not modify the `buffer`, you dont own it, you don't even know if `buffer[maximumBytes]` is in allocated memory.

Comment: As buffer was defined as unsigned char* type, seems there is no way to handle Unicode.

Comment: `\u20320` is not representable in clasic code pages (`?` is used as replacement character). You can use `SF_UNICODE` and insert data into `wstring` (remeber to divide `maximumBytes` by `2`) or `SF_USECODEPAGE` with `CP_UTF8`. Don't add NUL character at end, explicitly specify length instead.

Comment: @MOMING   hi, I'm curious if your problem has been solved (with the help of the method given above).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT, not yet...